# Page jumps to top when clicking image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a lot of pictures on the page, one under other.When i click one of them, will zoom them and also will refresh/jump at the begining of the page. How can i stop that ? This is the code :

```
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="house.jpg" id="house1" width="200" height="150" onclick="function1()">
```

CSS:

```
  .mystyle{
    position: fixed;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40%;
    transform:scale(5);
}
.mystyle2{
    float: right;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

JS:

```
function function1(){
    var house = document.getElementById("house1");
    if(house.className == "mystyle")
        house.className = "mystyle2";
    else
        house.className = "mystyle";

}
```

Comment: Why do you need `<a>` around the `<img>`?

Comment: onClick return false.

Comment: Its gonna be a link.

Comment: It's already a link: to the top of the page...

Comment: remove `href = "#"` and use `cursor:pointer` in css to show a hand cursor: `<a style="text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer" >`

Comment: Removing the href attr breaks keyboard accessibility. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `href="#"`

```
 <a style="text-decoration: none"><img src="house.jpg" id="house1" width="200" height="150" onclick="function1()">
```

Comment: Adding `return false` to the function won't do anything unless you update the img's `onclick` attribute to `onclick="return function1()"`.

Comment: Because `href` send the browser to a new page and in your case the link is `#`

Comment: Doing this breaks keyboard accessibility. You're better off replacing the `<a>` with a `<button>` and moving your `onclick="function1()"` to the button.

Comment: @Angelo Because the hash-symbol links to an anchor on the page and scrolls to it. If you don't add a tag to your hash it links to the body(?) tag.

Comment: @danielnixon no it doesn't just add `tabindex=1` like this `<a href=link2page.html tabindex=0 >Here</a>`

Comment: @ Werner that is correct in his case `#` means jump to unknown `id` attr which is the top of the page ie: `<a href="#id">go to id</a>
<div style="margin-top:4000px;"></div>
<a id="id">id</a>`

Comment: @Tambo you'd still need to move the `onclick` from the `img` to the `a`. You'd probably also want to add `role="button"` to the `a` because it really isn't a link. Or you could just use a real `button` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a semantic, accessible solution (unlike those already posted):

```
<button onclick="function1()">
    <img src="house.jpg" id="house1" width="200" height="150" alt="house">
<button>
```

Note:

- There is no link involved here, so *don't use an `<a>` tag*. Use a real `<button>`. This avoids all the `href` shenanigans.
- Move `onclick` from the `<img>` to the `<button>`. This gives you keyboard accessibility for free.
- Give the `<img>` alt text. I've just picked "house" because it was implied by the file name.
- You're better off getting rid of the `onclick` attribute and hooking up the JavaScript from an external js file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function function1(event){
    var house = document.getElementById("house1");
    if(house.className == "mystyle")
        house.className = "mystyle2";
    else
        house.className = "mystyle";

//return false;
//or

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="house.jpg" id="house1" width="200" height="150" onclick="function1()"/>
  </a>
```

Comment: Adding `return false` to the function won't do anything unless you update the img's `onclick` attribute to `onclick="return function1()"`. (But either way an explanation is in order...)

Comment: then add e.preventDefault();

Comment: Adding `e.preventDefault()` won't help because `onclick="function1()"` doesn't pass the event object to the function. And your update doesn't work because `onclick="function1"` doesn't call the function at all.

Comment: sorry .i will cross ones again

Comment: Have you tested it? It'd need to be `onclick="function1(event)"`. Seems to me that returning false along with the minor change from my original comment is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you refresh the page every time you click on an image which is inside an anchor with `href="#"`.

Just remove the `#` or use jquery:

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it's position fixed using css position property.
e.g position:fixed

Comment: Did you notice the code in the question already sets `position:fixed`, but only on every second click? Setting it permanently to `position:fixed` would break the whole point of responding to the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<a>` elements and keep only `<img>` or wrap them by some other elements like `<div>` or `<li>`. Since your javascript only changes style, there is no purpose for links.

Comment: The element you want is a regular old <button>. Your suggested elements would all cause accessibility issues.

Answer (score -1):

use javascript:void(0); instead of # in anchor tag,

for example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

This would help you,
keep coding :)